HTTP Redirects me to WWW./ (Ubuntu 22.04.4)
as the title states. I enter http://xxxxx or xxxx.xxx and it redirects me to a blank page with the url www./ for some reason.  If I enter https://xxxx or simply connect via ip x.x.x.x it allows the connection. I setup some redirections in my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/.conf which is the following. How can I get my http redirect to point towards https properly?
config

When is the last time you ran apt update and apt upgrade. You may be behind in updates.

@David I had to rebuild the configs yesterday and thought I re-updated. Updated and now the redirect works with just the URL but not if I add http:// at the beginning. Still redirects me to www./  Not a huge issue just slightly annoying that I can't find the cause.

@AustinAdkison You can't rule out the website itself doing the redirection, or a cached thing in your browser.  You may want to check both.
